# Is there a word for the relationship between a sequential series of tasks where each one is dependent on completion of the one before it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the backward, dependency between items that must be completed in a specific order, one after another.

"A series of *interdependent* tasks."

Is there a word that is more specific than interdependent? I don't want to imply that multiple tasks might depend on multiple other tasks. I also don't want to imply that two or more tasks might share dependencies between themselves at the same time. Only one task at a time has dependency on its prerequisite and the dependency relationship only goes in one direction.

Comment: I would simply suggest "A necessarily sequential set of tasks", as opposed to "a necessary set of tasks".

Comment: It is NOT an answer. I'm not sure what kind of tasks they are , but I would suggest considering *follow-on tasks* or *chain tasks* or *chain-kind-of tasks*.

Comment: chain tasks? Are those task performed by a chain? [ha ha]

Comment: Probably :) ....

Comment: Is the interdependence what you want to express, or would the sequential nature do? Compare assembling a watch (task dependency) with mowing a series of lawns (only time dependency).

Comment: @Lawrence yes, it is the dependence relationship that I'm looking to describe, not the overall series of tasks.

Comment: "Steps"   Assembly instructions usually have 'steps' - which carry a strong implication of them being sequential, although there can be parrallell steps where some steps might assemble a front and some parts assemble the rear .. then you combine the two and continue forward.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Reference has '**sequentially dependent task**'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **subsequent**

As in, set of subsequent tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**in succession** from succeed [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/succession?s=t)

> To come **next** in time or order; the coming of one person or thing after another in order, sequence, or in the course of events:

As in:

"A set of tasks done in succession"

Answer (score 0):

[Procedure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/procedure) : A *series* of actions conducted *in a certain order* or manner.

Answer (score -1):

**List** has a very precise meaning in mathematical or computer science domains, which seems to apply here.

Would  a *”a **list** of tasks”* make sense?

> In computer science, a **list** or **sequence** is an abstract data type that represents a countable number of **ordered** values, where the same value may occur more than once. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)

This is in contrast with a **set** which has no order.